# Sort Mult-dimensional Array with DateFormat as Key

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Is it possible to sort array with a special date format for a key?

I am pulling a list of records from a MySql db and casting the data

```
$sql = ' SELECT people.*    
DATE_FORMAT(people.started_at, ' . $dateformat . ') AS start_date,
//etc.
```

This is the date format, which can changed based up on parameters the user sets:

*`$dateformat = "'%W, %b %d %y'";`*

Once I get the record set back, I then organize and group them based up the start date, with this function:

```
private function groupDataByKey ( $data, $key ) {
      $groups = [];
      foreach ($data as $item) {
       $date = $item[ $key ];
       if (!isset( $groups[ $date ] )) {
          $groups[ $date ] = [];
       }
      array_push( $groups[ $date ], $item );
     }

     return $groups;
}
```

Grouping the array by the start_date:

`$groups = $this->groupDataByKey( $people, 'start_date' );`

Which gives me this format:

```
["Sunday, Aug 05 18"]=>{//array data},
["Sunday, Jul 08 18"]=>{//array data},  
["Friday, Aug 04 18"]=>{//array data}, 
["Monday, Jul 16 18"]=>{//array data}
//etc
```

Which is great, but the Dates are not in order.

The reason I went into more detail about *how* I get the data is so that you can see if there is away to do what I want along the way.

*Is there a way to sort the array based upon the date key?*

I tried `ksort($groups)`, but that orders them alphabetically by the Day of the week.

Comment: Logically, I would think sorting the query by the started_at column would be sufficient.

Comment: Try to avoid doing date formatting at the SQL level. Whenever possible do it in the application layer and take into account the particular preferences of the actual user viewing the data. This includes time-zone, language and formatting concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort the query itself, then the way you are grouping the items should keep them in order by date.

```
SELECT people.*    
DATE_FORMAT(people.started_at, ' . $dateformat . ') AS start_date
...
ORDER BY people.started_at;
```

Otherwise, you could use uksort to provide your own function for sorting the groups.

```
uksort($groups, function($a, $b) {
     return strtotime($a) - strtotime(b);
});
```